# Does Google penalize sites on "commercial" country code domains such as .me or .tv?

Tags: google, top-level-domains, country-specific

If I am thinking about using one of the 'fancy' top level domains such as `.me` or `.tv` should I be worried about how Google treats such domains?

Or to put it another way, if all other things are equal (good content, links etc.), will Google regard a `.tv` or `.me` as equal to a traditional `.com` or `co.uk` site?

Comment: Official Answer: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1347922

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are no penalties or preferences given for TLDs in `google.com`. All TLDs are treated equally in a `google.com` web search.

However, TLDs do affect your search results for country specific searches. For example, a `.me` or `.tv` domain will not rank as well as a `.us` website in a `google.us` web search. Also, a `.co.uk` site will rank better then a `.us` site in a `google.co.uk` search. This is because country specific searches give precedence to local websites.

So if you are targeting a specific country or region, try to use the TLD for that country or region. If not then the TLD does not make a difference.

Comment: Since you can set a target country for your site in Google webmaster tools, presumably doing so would negate the effect of this?

Comment: I don't know if this is 100% true. I've always heard that .edu and .gov sites get treated a little nicer when it comes to pagerank, which makes sense since not just anyone can register those.

Comment: That's not true for two reasons. Pagerank has nothing to do with TLDs. PR is all about link popularity (it's a published formula). And .edu and .gov pages can be *modified* by regular people. 99% of .edu pages are made by *STUDENTS*. .gov is less abused but it can have bogus info put up. And since Google already has a good formula for ranking pages they don't need to use arbitrary bonuses especially ones that aren't based on facts.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for closing my post and redirecting me here. Still the same question though: will there be any difference in local search between a .com.sg domain and a .sg domain?

Comment: Technically `google.com` is `google.us` or at least `.us` redirects to `.com`.  I'm not sure if I should I should edit the question but the example properly isn't ideal.  I'm not sure if this means there is no `google.us` or no global `google.com`

Comment: I believe the core of this answer is incorrect.  I believe there is no way to disable demographics search on Google therefore all searches are in fact country specific/demographic.  I hope I am wrong but it does appear to be the case.

Answer (score 14):

In short: no, Google does not penalize `.me` or `.tv` sites by default.

Google would generally treat `.me` and `.tv` domains the same as `.com`. They're all seen as generic TLDs (gTLDs), so they are not country-specific by default (technically, `.me` and `.tv` are ccTLDs, but since they're used so widely, Google treats them as gTLDs).

`.co.uk` is a bit different - it's a ccTLD, so it's country-specific. For those, it's possible that they are shown a bit higher in the local search results in the UK. However, you can achieve the same effect by using Google Webmaster Tools' geotargeting feature. More on that is at http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/03/working-with-multi-regional-websites.html.

For other search engines, it's probable that `.me` & `.tv` are also seen as gTLDs, but I'm not 100% certain (these things can change over time). Also, in general, unless you can specify geotargeting with them, they will use the server's location for geotargeting of gTLDs - so if you have a `.com` website hosted in the UK, it's probable that they will use that as a signal that you are trying to target the UK.

Comment: is there a list somewhere of the technically country-specific TLDs which Google treats as generic? And does Google state this policy openly anywhere?

Comment: See this webmaster tools help document.  It explains the policy and gives a list of all the generic top level domains: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1347922

Answer (score 0):

I see this is an older post but I have a very current instance where I can see that a .us name ranks worse than a .com name. The .com name is surfacing on google page 1, based on a search term "moonshine still". One site is coming up on page 1 every time, even at a time when that site was down and for a long time it didn't have any content. My site, on the other hand; I have a .us name, and it hasn't come up any better than page 3 in all the years I've had it. I have current content, relevant text that should help my rank, and I still can't get any higher.

Why would a site be such high rank after many months of not having any content, while others would fall so far behind? The only thing I can figure out is the .us name so that is my answer. Get a .com name if at all possible.

Comment: Unlike `.me` and `.tv` asked in this question, `.us` is not a generic top level domain to Google.  Google has a list of country code domains that it treats as generic in the "more about determination" section of this page: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/62399?hl=en