# Tonga domains for commercial websites

Tags: top-level-domains

Does anyone knows disadvantatges on installing a commercial website on Tonga domains? I mean, maybe it is not advisable to link a website for .TO domains (these domains tends to be for torrents, for instance).

Answer (score 3):

When you run a local search, international and local TLDs usually gets more priority compared to all the others TLDs.

It means, if you search on `google.it`, a business with a `.it` or `.com` domain has more chances to be in higher position compared to a `.to` domain.

That said, it really depends on your business. Honestly, I won't really be concerned by search engines. Instead, I would first make sure my business doesn't rely on TLD managed by low-quality authorities to [avoid business risks](http://domainnamewire.com/2010/10/06/libya-shuts-down-ly-link-shortener/).

Answer (score 0):

[It basically only affects local search.](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2330/does-google-penalize-me-or-tv-sites/2331#2331)

Comment: These days .to domains are only going to rank in Tonga.   To rank globablly Google has to add country code top level domain to the list they have here: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/62399?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

One thing to consider is that email from .to addresses is often more likely to be flagged as spam, due primarily to it's common association with piracy and hacker sites. This may well have an effect if your site sends out emails. Other than that, there is the potential problem of visitors making the same association, which could possibly be detrimental.