# CO.CC domains SEO disadvantages

Tags: seo, domains, free

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Google penalize .me or .tv sites?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2330/does-google-penalize-me-or-tv-sites)

There is a free domain service http://www.co.cc . We can setup DNS settings at co.cc . But is there any SEO disadvantages for CO.CC domains?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My mistake, as John said, a domain being free is not a rank factor.

Comment: Wow. This is answer is wrong. A domain being free is **NOT** a ranking factor.

Comment: -1 do you have a source to back up your claims?

Answer (score 1):

I think having a .co.cc subdomain will rank lower in search engines then having a .com domain name. Last July, Google actually removed 11,000,000+ .co.cc websites from their listings due to the large amount of .co.cc websites containing malware and spam. If you want to be indexed by search engines, I say just spend the $10 (or less) on a .com domain name.

Comment: source: http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/07/06/google_cans_11m_dot_co_dot_cc_sites/ Those domains are indexed now, see https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=site%3Aco.cc

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any particular disadvantage with `.co.cc` as far as SEO is concerned. But you should take care of this fact that if after few years your website is a success and you want to purchase your own domain name, at that time all your SEO efforts for this `.co.cc` domain will go in vain and you have to rework on SEO for `.com` or `.net` domain at that time.

Comment: -1 do you have a source to back up your claims?

Answer (score -1):

I think they have low priority than other paid domain names but in the last what it matters is the keywords. If you write keyword rich content than you can have a better page rank...

Comment: -1 do you have a source to back up your claims?