# How do search engines treat domains created out of country codes (e.g bit.ly)

Tags: seo, domain-hacks

I have a site that has a domain name that is a word created out of a country code (like bit.ly awe.sm favo.rs)  My question is how do search engines handle these.

For example, would a search on favors return a link to favors given their search criteria?

For on site copy, should the domain be used or the underlying word without the dot in it?

I'd like to know which would be most optimal to use in site copy for SEO purposes.

Answer (score 2):

1) See [this answer for how TLD affects SEO](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2330/does-google-penalize-me-or-tv-sites/2331#2331)

2) favo.rs will *probably not* do as well as `favors.rs` or `favors` in the copy as the `.` is probably a word delimiter so breaking it up in the URL/domain name/copy prevents it from being recognized as "favors".

Comment: Shouldn't the question be voted on to close because it is a duplicate (I can't vote on it for that purpose, but if this was a SO question, I definitely would).

Comment: @casperOne, It's different enough to remain open. If the question was only about the domain extension it would be an exact duplicate. But asking about how the search engines handle words which are comprised of the domain name and TLD is different.