# How Google value .in/.info domains currently?

Tags: seo, google, domains, top-level-domains

As `.info` domain price increased, how much Google value `.info` domain now? Also `.in` domain is now cost less then `.info` (for first year).

Is Google going to less value `.in` domain now? I have couple of `.in` domain and now I am really scared about that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *cost* of registering a domain name under a given TLD has nothing to do with how Google–or any search engine–would rank it for search results.

What registrar would this even be based on? Right now, NetSol registers `.info` at $34.99, but GoDaddy is offering them at $1.99 (down from a normal $11.99). The difference in their pricing for `.in` is about the same. Other registrars don't offer `.info` at all, and I don't think any one registrar handles *all* the TLD, so there wouldn't be a central source.

As a sideline, you might also be interested in the answers to [this previous question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2330/does-google-penalize-me-or-tv-sites) about Google penalizing some TLD. (They don't.)

Comment: over the years google did penalize .info domains right? One of the reason was `.info` was low cost domain and spammers used it extensively. There are lots of articles on the web that people have a good `.info` domain and don't get ranking. My concern is can same thing happen to `.in` domain too?

Comment: @Sisir: No. As Su specified, `.info` and `.in` are top level domains, which have never and will never get penalized in Google. Also, `.in` is the TLD for *India*, so you should only use that if your site is targeted to Indians or is related to India in some way.

Comment: @Sisir If *a* site doesn't rank well, there's probably a reason *that* site doesn't rank well. It doesn't tell you much about the TLD. If in fact there are "good" sites on .info, and I'm sure there are, it would be **extremely** questionable for a search engine to blacklist them wholeslae. You say there are "lots" of articles saying so. How many versus the [7.5](http://www.webhosting.info/registries/) - [8](http://www.dailychanges.com/) *million* .info domains that are registered? Keep in mind this is the kind of thing people will only write to complain about.

Comment: Also, [here](http://www.seroundtable.com/archives/017226.html) is an instance from 2008 of .info(and Blogspot) domains seemingly falling out of search results. They were back within hours, and were almost certainly a glitch of some kind.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat: sometime its hard to find a brand able domain name on `.com` or `.net` so people are looks for regional TLD's. Here is one http://outside.in. Do you think its a bad idea to having a regional domain if my target visitors are from all over the world? If so why?

Comment: @Sisir some domains may work well if they are memorable, like outside.in or a .tv domain. But they should be avoided where possible IMO because they are more difficult to remember and may not rank as well outside of their intended region.