# Rank value of domain extensions in Google

Tags: seo, google, domains

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Google penalize .me or .tv sites?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2330/does-google-penalize-me-or-tv-sites)

Is there any definitive information on how google values different domain extensions in its ranking algorithms?

My assumption, all other things being equal, is .com > .net > .org > .co etc.