# Is it disadvantageous to use a .me domain?

Tags: domains, top-level-domains, business

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Google penalize .me or .tv sites?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2330/does-google-penalize-me-or-tv-sites)

In a scenario like the following, **should I go for the .net or the .me domain?**

Assumptions:

- I have a relatively informal website about *eating*.
- eating.com is already taken.

Should I go for:

1. **eating.net** (might confuse visitors because the .com is occupied by someone else / a competitor)
2. **eat.me** (because it is so catchy)

I have heard (just word of mouth) that Google would give less priority to .me domains, is that true?

*PS: eating/eat is just an example, but my actual sitename is (almost) as catchy.*