# Pointing .com and .ca domain names

Tags: seo, domains, local-seo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Google penalize .me or .tv sites?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2330/does-google-penalize-me-or-tv-sites)

I have a `.com` and `.ca` domain extensions for my business.

I have heard that it's better to have `.ca` for SEO as my business targets local customers, is that correct?

Also is it better to make the `.com` resolve to the same server as the `.ca` or make it redirect to it?

Answer (score 1):

I am sure others will be along with more comprehensive answers, but I'm firmly of the view that a single domain should be used for the site, with any secondary domains `redirected` not just resolving to the same server.

This also applies to non-www and www aliases

This way, you only have one set of incoming links, and one set of SEO scores/pagerank

As to whether .ca is better than .com - we have the same discussion in .uk and I'm yet to be convinced either way.

However, good **content** will make a big difference...

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Andrew about the redirecting all domains and aliases to one domain.

About the TLD, I must say it doesn't make much different for your local customers, just put yourself in their place and see which TLD do you trust more? personally I prefer .com for my business instead of .us or in your case .ca

I feel it's different in the UK or Germany though, .uk and .de are more popular for example. but I believe for US or Canada a .com is more acceptable.

Just remember, if you're using a generic TLD such .com, then you could benefit from telling Google that your site is targeted for visitors from Canada.

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=62399

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182192