# Does the .ending on a domain need to be relevant?

Tags: domains

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Google penalize .me or .tv sites?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2330/does-google-penalize-me-or-tv-sites)

I see a lot of people now opting to use

> myname.im

or

> myname.me

But after doing some checking, i found that `.im` domain names are meant to be Isle of Man endings. Is this correct, and does it matter that people opt to use this domain ending if they are not even based anywhere near the Isle of Man.

It is Ok to use a domain ending purely for how good it sounds is what I'm really after. Or is it bad practice to do this.

Answer (score 0):

[.im](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.im) is ccTLD for *Isle of Man* and [.me](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.me) is for *Montenegro*

As w3d mentioned, one part of your comment is answered on another post: [Does Google penalize .me or .tv sites?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2330/does-google-penalize-me-or-tv-sites)

You can use any domain from any country that is available, it doesn't affect your SEO score, the only important thing is how the whole name looks together.