# .com vs .me for personal and blogging sites. Which one is good regarding seo

Tags: domains, subdomain, multiple-domains, top-level-domains

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Google penalize .me or .tv sites?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2330/does-google-penalize-me-or-tv-sites)

I basically have a domain under my name with .com extension. I am planning to use it for my portfolio and also as a regular blog.

Now considering SEO and ranking stuff, what is the best way to implement this.

**myname.com** - *Portfolio* || **myname.com/blog** - *Blog page*

(or)

**myname.com** - *Blog* || **myname.me** - *Portfolio*

i have absolutely no idea on how .tld's impact SEO and Ranking, so i seek the experts advice on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We need a catch-all for this question. This is the second time in as many days.

Comment: When i asked this question, i found no title with 'com vs me extensions for portfolio and blogging'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding to my experiences, .com is the very best TLD for (google-)rankings.
Besides different Domain-names will split your link-power, while the deeplink-option will bring you synergy-effects for both sites. Just make sure not to go TOO deep with the URL (2-3 levels is OK).

Comment: So basically .me extension will be not necessary for me right ?

Comment: yes. Go for the .com and the /blog/-Directory.

Comment: You could get the .me, too and 301-redirect it to .com/blog/, if you like to use the .me-name - but it won't bring you any advantages in SEO.

Comment: Thank you very much mene. I will go for the .com only. These days..rankings are more important than professional names :)

Comment: This depends pretty much on your business. ;-)
You could tick my answer if your're happy with it. thanks. :)

Comment: Yep, gave it to ya :)