# SEO Optimization and Country Coded Domains

Tags: seo, local-seo

I have a sight hosted on .ie domain but it is near the NI(Northern Ireland) border and the business has a lot of NI traffic. So when someone searches in NI with certain key words I would like the site to appear in the results, it currently doesn't.

I have seen this post

[Does Google penalize sites on "commercial" country code domains such as .me or .tv?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2330/does-google-penalize-sites-on-commercial-country-code-domains-such-as-me-or/2331#2331)

But was wondering the best way around this. Would it be to create a .co.uk version that redirects to the .ie site? Or would I have to create a separate .co.uk site?

Any help appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Most country code sites won't rank in Google outside their respective country.  Google provides absolutely no mechanism to expand .ie domain to rank outside of Ireland.

You have two options:

1. Move your website to a generic top level domain such as `.com`
2. Duplicate your website on a `.co.uk` domain name.